# Retain empty lists in rrapply::rrapply()

Tags: r

Is there an option that allows me to retain list entries that have values that are 0-length lists in the `how="melt"` option?  In the below, I'd like to retain the `B` and `E` entries.

Note: @akrun gave an initial solution when I had a simpler reprex here (I did not have the 0-length list at `E` in the original).  I originally accepted, realized I needed a more complex example, and used @akrun 's solution as a basis to my accepted solution below.

```r
library(rrapply)
lst <- list(A=1, B=list(), C=list(D=letters[1:3], E=list()))
str(lst)
#> List of 3
#>  $ A: num 1
#>  $ B: list()
#>  $ C:List of 2
#>   ..$ D: chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
#>   ..$ E: list()

# Melting it drops things that has 0-length lists, like B and E:
rrapply(lst, how="melt")
#>   L1   L2   value
#> 1  A <NA>       1
#> 2  C    D a, b, c
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer, based on @akrun 's solution above.

```r
library(rrapply)
lst <- list(A=1, B=list(), C=list(D=letters[1:3], E=list()))
str(lst)
#> List of 3
#>  $ A: num 1
#>  $ B: list()
#>  $ C:List of 2
#>   ..$ D: chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
#>   ..$ E: list()

# Melting it drops things that has 0-length lists, like B and E:
rrapply(lst, how="melt")
#>   L1   L2   value
#> 1  A <NA>       1
#> 2  C    D a, b, c

#;; Here is how you can retain those entries that have 0-length lists, but
#;; you have to change the 0-length list to NA:
rrapply(lst, classes = "list"
        , condition = \(x) length(x) == 0
        , f = \(x) NA
        , how="recurse") |>
    rrapply(how="melt")
#>   L1   L2   value
#> 1  A <NA>       1
#> 2  B <NA>      NA
#> 3  C    D a, b, c
#> 4  C    E      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The empty list elements can be recursively changed to NA and then `melt`

```
rrapply(lst, classes = "list", f = \(x) if(!length(x)) NA else x) |>
    rrapply(how = "melt")
```

-output

```
  L1   L2   value
1  A <NA>       1
2  B <NA>      NA
3  C    D a, b, c
```

Comment: Works, thanks!  The value is NA rather than an empty list, but for my purposes, it works just fine, and I can do some other hacks to get at the original and see if it is an empty list.  The big win is retaining the record of there being an entry at all...

Comment: FYI -- after using on my real-life experiment, I realize my reprex was not complex enough.  This solution doesn't work with nested empty lists.  I'm going to edit my original question to have a more complex example.  I have the solution, based on your solution here.  If you want to use my solution as yours, feel free, and I'll delete what I post as an answer in favor of yours.

Comment: @mpettis i guess the `how = "recurse"` is the key as in your post