# Indexing the list postion of all intermediate lists, even if lists are empty (package {rrapply})

Tags: r

I have a input data structure that ends up having leaf nodes being empty lists and the parent lists just contain sublists.  The relevant info ends up in the list attributes, and I have to extract that.  To that end,  I need to get index positions to *all* list elements and use those coordinates to walk the list.  `{rrapply}` has been working for lists with elements, but I cannot figure out how to get the positions of lists with no non-list sub-elements.

Below is a reprex showing the parts I get `{rrapply}` to get, and what it misses, and a very old-school solution at the end that I coded up to work.  So I have a solution, but I am looking to see if I can get `{rrapply}` to do this, and understand why I am not able to get it to do what I want.

```r
# stackoverflow_list-element-position-vector.R

library(rrapply)
library(purrr)

# A sample list
lst <-
    list(
        list(),
        list(
            list(),
            list(),
            list()
        ),
        list(a=1:3
             , list()
        )
    )

# Misses all of the empty lists, just the sublist with the name "a":
rrapply(lst,
        f = \(x, .xpos) .xpos,
        how="melt") |>
    pluck("value") |>
    str()
#> List of 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 1

#;; From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76124073/1022967
#;; Misses the positions of the intermediate nodes, which I need too.
#;; i.e., misses lists at position 2 and 3.
rrapply(lst
        , classes = "list"
        , condition = \(x) length(x) == 0
        , f = \(x) NA
        , how="recurse") |>
    rrapply(f = \(x, .xpos) .xpos
            , how="melt") |>
    pluck("value") |>
    str()
#> List of 6
#>  $ : int 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 2
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 3
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 2

#;; Take a list, return flat list of all of the positions of list
#;; elements.
#;; Real old-school technique...
listEltPos <- function(llst) {
    work_lst <-
        list(list(coord_vec = integer(0), comp = llst))
    output_lst <-
        list()
    
    while (TRUE) {
        if (length(work_lst) == 0) break
        
        # Pop off head of work_lst
        e <-
            pluck(work_lst, 1)
        work_lst <-
            work_lst[-1]
        
        # If element isn't a list, nothing more to process
        if (class(e$comp) != "list") next
        
        # If here, it is a list.  If length is 0, return
        if (length(e$comp) == 0) next
        
        # Otherwise, it has entries.  Find relative coordinate of the entry
        # and add that to the output list and make a list element with that
        # coordinate and the corresponding subelement.
        subElementPositions <-
            seq(length(e$comp))
        
        for (i in subElementPositions) {
            # Append local pos to the overall coordinate vector
            newPosVec <-
                c(e$coord_vec, i)
            sub_e <-
                pluck(e$comp, i)
            
            # Add current new pos to the output queue
            output_lst <-
                append(output_lst, list(newPosVec))
            
            # Append subelements and their updated positions to the work queue
            work_lst <-
                append(work_lst, list(list(coord_vec=newPosVec, comp=sub_e)))
        }
        rm(i)
    }

    output_lst
}

#;; This is what I am hoping for
listEltPos(lst) |>
    str()
#> List of 8
#>  $ : int 1
#>  $ : int 2
#>  $ : int 3
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 2
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 3
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach using `rrapply()` could be to walk the nested list with `how = "recurse"` and keeping track of all encountered values of `.xpos` by assigning them to a global variable (outside the function scope):

```
library(rrapply)

## initialize empty list
allpos <- list()

## walk nested list and append indices to `allpos`
invisible(
  rrapply(
    lst,
    classes = c("list", "integer"),
    how = "recurse",
    f = \(x, .xpos) {
      allpos <<- append(allpos, list(.xpos))
      x
    }
  )
)

str(allpos)
#> List of 8
#>  $ : int 1
#>  $ : int 2
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 2
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 3
#>  $ : int 3
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 2
```

Note: this will not be efficient for very large lists in which case it may be better to determine the size of `allpos` in advance, instead of iteratively appending new values to the list.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to see if I can wrap this in a function so that I can update `allpos` in the function body environment and return that, and not pollute the `.GlobalEnv`.  But that's a separate question and one that I think will be straightforward to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is exactly what I want.  I am adding here the way I wrapped that solution in a function so that I don't do any updating to the `.GlobalEnv`.  I also changed one argument to `classes` to do `ANY` vs. `integer`, because I might have more than integer (which I didn't lay out in the original example).

```r
# A sample list, slightly different content, has an integer and character
# element.
lst <-
    list(
        list(),
        list(
            list(),
            list()
        ),
        list(a=1:3
             , list()
             , c= letters[1:4]
        )
    )


# From Joris solution here -- changes 
getListNodePos <- function(llst) {
    library(rrapply)

    #;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771942/how-can-i-reference-the-local-environment-within-a-function-in-r 
    locEnv <- environment()
    
    ## initialize empty list
    allpos <- list()
    
    ## walk nested list and append indices to `allpos`
    invisible(
        rrapply(
            llst,
            classes = c("list", "ANY"),
            how = "recurse",
            f = \(x, .xpos) {
                assign("allpos", append(allpos, list(.xpos)), envir = locEnv)
                x
            }
        )
    )
    
    allpos
}

# Show the indexes
getListNodePos(lst) |>
    str()
#> List of 8
#>  $ : int 1
#>  $ : int 2
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 2 2
#>  $ : int 3
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 1
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 2
#>  $ : int [1:2] 3 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>